# How do I get a full feed of commits with all changes from github

Tags: github

Here is feed for commits made in jquery project. http://github.com/feeds/jquery/commits/jquery/master

This feed does not contain all the changes made in the source code. It just contains the commit title. How do I get feed so that I could see the code diff in my feed reader rather than coming to github for each and every commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible (at least from github) - they don't put diffs in the feeds/hooks because diffs can vary widely in size, up to thousands or more lines.